# Cocos2d: how can I get a subclass of sprite to call a selector when touched?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

How can I get a subclass of sprite to call a selector when touched?

I want a Sprite to react to touch and call a selector when touch is ended. I know how to get it to react to touches but I do not know how to specify which selector I should call.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to be able to set a target and selector on a sprite?

You can do that by setting up a method that stores a target and a selector in an instance variable.

```
__weak id _target;
SEL _selector;

-(void)setTarget:(id)target andSelector:(SEL)selector
{
     _target = target;
     _selector = selector;
}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded...
{
    [_target performSelector:_selector];
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that was what I was after. Sorry for not being able to express this properly before.

Answer (score 1):

In layer, first enable touch and add ccTouchesBegan to track touch.

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

You can use this function to find touch.

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], touchLocation) )
    {
        [sprite youTouched];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is not what I was asking for but is an ok alternative